# Angular 6 MatSnackBar works in Chrome but not in IE11

Tags: angular, angular-material, snackbar

Spent a few hours now trying to figure this out, MatSnackBar is working perfectly fine in Chrome but trhows a weird error in IE11.

My setup:

app.shared.module.ts:

```
import { MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material';
```

my-test.component.ts:

```
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
...
    constructor(
    private snackbar: MatSnackBar,
...
this.snackbar.open('Submitted','Close',
            {
                duration: 3000,
            });
```

This is fine in Chrome but in IE11 it throws this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

to polyfill.ts

Comment: Tried that - no luck.